# Attempting to add an increment method to a time class

Tags: java

I am attempting to add an increment method for a time class I have. I have modified the original code to only have one private integer "totalseconds" that reads the amount of seconds since midnight. That part of the code works fine but now I am trying to create a method that increments the setSecond, setMinute, and setHour. The problem (I believe) I am having is that these set methods all receive their values from totalseconds not int hour, int minute, int second as before. When I run the test for it the way I have it now I get errors at lines 36, 75 (when attempted to increment seconds via Tick method) and 101 (again only when incrementing seconds via Tick method). I have attached both the Time2 class and Time2Test app for reference.

```
    public class Time2 {
    private int totalseconds;
    //no argument constructor
    public Time2()
    {
        this(0,0,0); //invoke constructor with three arguments default to 0
    }

    //constructor with hour supplied minute and second default to 0
    public Time2(int hour)
    {
        this(hour, 0, 0); //invoke constructor with 3 args
    }

    //constructor with hour and minute supplied seconds default to 0
    public Time2(int hour, int minute)
    {
        this(hour, minute, 0); //invoke constructor with 3 args
    }

    //Time2 constructor with hour minute and second supplied also tests

    public Time2(int hour, int minute, int second)
    {       
        this.totalseconds = (hour * 3600);
        this.totalseconds += (minute * 60);
        this.totalseconds += (second);
    }

    public Time2(Time2 time)
    {
        //invoke constructor with 2 args
        this(time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond());
    }

    // SET and GET methods start here, also Universal time conversion and check
    public void setTime(int hour, int minute, int second) 
    {
        if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hour must be 0-23");
        if (minute < 0 || minute >= 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minute must be 0-59");
        if (second < 0 || second >= 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hour must be 0-59");

         this.totalseconds = (hour * 3600);
         this.totalseconds += (minute * 60);
         this.totalseconds += second;
    }

    //validate and set hour
    public void setHour(int hour)
    {
        if (hour < 0 || hour >= 23)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hour must be 0-23");
        this.totalseconds = (hour * 3600);
    }

    //validate and set minute
    public void setMinute(int minute)
    {
        if (minute < 0 || minute >= 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minute must be 0-59");
        this.totalseconds += (minute * 60);
    }

    //validate and set second
    public void setSecond(int second)
    {
        if (second < 0 || second >= 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Second must be 0-59");
        this.totalseconds += second;
    }
    //Get Methods start here

    //Get hour
    public int getHour()
    {
        return totalseconds / 3600;
    }

    //get minute
    public int getMinute()
    {
        return (totalseconds - (3600 * getHour())) / 60;
    }

    //get second
    public int getSecond()
    {
        return totalseconds - (3600 * getHour())- (60 * getMinute());
    }

    //Assignment 1-2 tick methods start here.
    public void Tick()
    {
        setSecond(totalseconds ++);
        if (totalseconds >= 59) incrementMinute();
    }
    public void incrementMinute()
    {
        setMinute( totalseconds ++);
        if ( totalseconds >= 59) incrementHour();
    }
    public void incrementHour()
    {
        setHour ( this.totalseconds ++);
    }
    //convert our string to universal format (HH:MM:SS)
    public String ToUniversalString()
    {
        return String.format(
        "%02d:%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute(), getSecond());
    }

    //conver to standard format (H:MM:SS AM or PM)
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s",((getHour() == 0 || getHour() ==
        12) ? 12 : getHour() % 12), getMinute(), getSecond(), (getHour()
        < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"));
    }

}//end class Time2



    public class Time2Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Time2 t1 = new Time2(); //00:00:00
        Time2 t2 = new Time2(2); //02:00:00 
        Time2 t3 = new Time2(21, 34); //21:34:00
        Time2 t4 = new Time2(12, 25, 42); //12:25:42
        Time2 t5 = new Time2(t4); //12:25:42

        System.out.println("Constructed with:");
        displayTime("t1: all default arguments", t1);
        displayTime("t2: hour specified; defaults for minute and second", t2);
        displayTime("t3: hour and minute supplied second defaulted", t3);
        displayTime("t4: hour minute and second supplied", t4);
        displayTime("t5: Time2 object t4 specified", t5);
        //attempt to initialize t6 with invalid args
        try
        {
            Time2 t6 = new Time2(27,74,99); //all invalid values
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            System.out.printf("%nException while initializing t6: %s%n",
                    e.getMessage());
        }


        System.out.println("Time before increment minute method");
        System.out.printf("%s\n", t4.toString());

        t4.Tick();
        t4.incrementMinute();
        t4.incrementHour();

        System.out.println("Time after increment minute method");
        System.out.printf("%s\n", t4.toString());
    }
    //display Time2 object in 24 hour and 12 hour formats
    private static void displayTime(String header, Time2 t)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s%n   %s%n   %s%n", header, t.ToUniversalString(),
                t.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. I very much doubt that you need this much code to demonstrate the problem. It's also not clear what you mean by "increments the setSecond, setMinute and setHour". They're methods - there's no such concept as incrementing a method.

Comment: Your first step should be to clearly document each method and specify what it's **supposed** to do. For example, if you call setHour(10) on 12:13:14, it becomes 10:00:00. But if you call setSecond(16) on 12:13:14, it becomes 12:13:30. This is completely inconsistent and illogical. Clearly writing the contract of each method is the first step of implementing them, and then testing the contract is respected. You should also have proper unit tests for each method before implementing the next one.